# How can I amend this to paste special values and use a path specified in a cell range

Tags: excel, vba

Currently this code works for me, but I am having problems amending it to do what I want.

There are 2 amends I am after

1. is to use a file path specified in a cell instead of in the script
2. when copying and pasting between workbooks to copy and paste special.  I have added a line to value to code before I paste it as when I try and paste special it doesn't seem to look through all my workbooks.

Just some background to the code:

I a folder with multiple sheets and I would like to take the data in the Noms tab from A8:BW (bottom row) and paste it in the workbook I am running the vba from into a sheet called Noms.  Each sheet would need to paste under the other.

```
Dim wkbDest As Workbook
Dim wkbSource As Workbook
Set wkbDest = ThisWorkbook
Dim LastRow As Long
Const strPath As String = "C:\Users\Amzy\Desktop\Noms\"
ChDir strPath
strExtension = Dir("*.xls*")
Do While strExtension <> ""
    
    Set wkbSource = Workbooks.Open(strPath & strExtension)
    With wkbSource
        LastRow = .Sheets("Noms").Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
        .Sheets("Noms").Range("A8:BW" & LastRow).Select:
         Selection.copy
         Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                :=False, Transpose:=False
        Selection.copy wkbDest.Sheets("Noms").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        .Application.CutCopyMode = False
        .Close SaveChanges:=False
    End With
    strExtension = Dir
Loop
```

Comment: You don't need to `Select`, nor `PasteSpecial`. One line is sufficient: `.Sheets("Nom").Range("A8:B8" & LastRow).Value = .Sheets("Nom").Range("A8:B8" & LastRow).Value`.

Comment: I have just amended it to this and nothing copies over from my other sheets.  Originally I had it so instead of .value in both it was copy then paste special and that didn't wok either.

Comment: "Nothing copies over from my other sheets"... that's because the code in the first comment is pasting values over itself, in the source workbook. If you want to paste values into a new workbook, then `With .Sheets("Noms").Range("A8:BW" & LastRow)`, `wkbDest.Sheets("Noms").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Value = .Value`, `End With`.